# Friend class definition

Tags: c++, methods, static, friend

Today I looked into the header source code of `boost::asio::ip::address` and found the following lines:

```
class address
{
  // I removed some irrelevant lines here...

  public:

  /// Compare addresses for ordering.
  friend bool operator>=(const address& a1, const address& a2)
  {
    return !(a1 < a2);
  }
};
```

Now I know what `friend` is for but I had never seen it followed by a definition, **inside a class definition**.

So my question is, what does this `friend` declaration do ? It seems to me that `operator>=` is not a method here, however there is no `static` keyword either.

Does `friend` replace `static` in this particular case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. It doesn't replace `static` because you don't need to qualify the name when you call the operator. It kind of does as you don't need a class instance to call it on.

It's like declaring the operator outside the class:

```
class address
{
  // I removed some irrelevant lines here...

  public:

  /// Compare addresses for ordering.
  friend bool operator>=(const address& a1, const address& a2);
};

inline bool operator>=(const address& a1, const address& a2)
{
   return !(a1 < a2);
}
```

You can access private and protected methods from the class.

Think of overloading the stream operator inside the class, the same technique can be applied.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what about the `namespace` of the function ? Does it have the same `namespace` the containing class it is declared into ?

Comment: @ereOn never thought of that. Since you need a class to use the operator, it will automatically go to the required namespace, but I can't tell if the operator itself is in the namespace.

Comment: For all practical purposes it will behave as if it had been declared in the namespace surrounding the class. (Let's forget about corner cases, like templated friends that are never used...).

Comment: @ereOn what @Bo has said, except that the operator is not visible except by ADL. So you need something associated to "address" to invoke it. For example `int main() { string x; x >= 10; }` will not invoke `operator>=` even if your `address` class is convertible from both `int` and `string`. The reason is because neither of `string` and `10` have `address` as their associated class. But if you do `address x; x >= 10;` it works because the `address` argument makes the `operator>=` visible (-> ADL) and then both arguments are passed/converted to `address const&`.

Comment: hm.. and what about class method `bool operator>=(const address&)`? is it neccessary to do `friend operator>= (const address& one, const address& two)` instead of `bool operator>=(const address& one)`?